# why this program compiles fine in C11 but not in C99?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, c99, c11

Consider following program: (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/inVtCg7v1GRnVsMz)) .

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Test
{
    int a;
};
typedef struct Test t;
typedef struct Test t;
int main()
{
    t T={9};
    printf("%d",T.a);
}
```

The program compiles fine in C11 compiler but fails in compilation in C99 compiler. Why? What is the reason?
My compiler gcc 4.8.1 gives following warnings:

```
[Warning] redefinition of typedef 't' [-Wpedantic]
[Note] previous declaration of 't' was here
```

Comment: Does the compiler give you a hint or does it just refuse to compile this without producing any error messages?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I haven't because I haven't got any votes left today, but probably because your question lacks thoroughness and the errors you are getting are missing.

Comment: @juanchopanza: by default GCC compiles this as a compiler extension but If I use -pedantic-errors option then it fails in compilation? Compiler gives warnings.

Comment: Interesting. And do you want to keep those warnings/errors secret? Or can you share them with us?

Comment: @PravasiMeet with GCC, compile with -std=c11 and -Wall then follow any warnings.

Comment: Develop a habit of including any error/warning messages from compilers/linkers.

Comment: @PravasiMeet if anything, complaining about downvotes will attract significantly more. And wether or not your question shows research and effort is for the community to decide, not you.

Comment: @tinky_winky: who says that? It is completely well defined.

Comment: @MartinJames That is not how SO works. You downvote to encourage edits. If the problems with the post are fixed, the downvote is no longer locked and can be removed.

Comment: Anyway, as a C nerd I think this was the most interesting question today, +1.

Comment: Found a duplicate when I was looking for a rationale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was (apparently) changed in C11. C99§6.7/3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except for tags as specified in 6.7.2.3.

C11§6.7/3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except that:
>
> — **a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does**, provided that type is not a variably modified type;
>
> — tags may be redeclared as specified in 6.7.2.3.

<s>While I can't find a rationale document for C11, my guess as to the reason for this change is to allow multiple `struct` `typedef`s, possibly over multiple headers. Since re-declaring `struct`/`union`/`enum` tags is allowed already and `typedef`ing `struct`s is a fairly common idiom.</s>

**Edit**

@Lundin has found the [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1360.htm) for this: it is to enhance compatibility with C++:

> C++ allows a typedef redefinition with the same name as a previous typedef to appear in the same scope, as long as it names the same type. Some C compilers allow similar typedef redefinition as an extension, though C99 does not allow it. Adding benign typedef redefinition to C1x would enhance consistency with C++, standardize some existing practice, and safely eliminate a constraint that is unhelpful and an occasional nuisance to users.

Comment: How weird is that? I believe you and upvoted, but I just sorta wonder why they did that?

Comment: @MartinJames it struck me as weird too. My guess would be to allow multiple `typedef`s of the same thing over multiple headers, just like tags can be. Especially since `typedef struct { ... } type;` combos are so popular.

Comment: I have some vague memory about C++ allowing multiple typedefs, so it could be an attempt to harmonize C with C++? As for what the rationale for it in C++ would be, I have no idea.

Comment: @Lundin doesn't C++ automagically `typedef` `struct`s to their tag (`struct foo { ... };` -> `typedef struct foo { ... } foo;`)? They might allow it to accomodate redundant `typedef`s coming over from C. So the harmonisation has come full circle :).

Comment: @Kninnug The answer to the duplicate I linked seems to suggest this was for C++ harmonization indeed. That's the only explanation I can find.

Comment: Found the [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1360.htm).

Comment: @Lundin nice. Edited my answer, for what it's still worth...